# How to restore ec2 instance. i dont have snaphot of the EC2, but the EC2 was not terminated it is up and running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For some reason, I would like to restore my EC2 instance. But I don't have any snapshot of that instance. Also, I won't able to SSH login to Ec2 instances. What is the alternate way to change the system settings to default?

Comment: can define what do you mean by `default settings` ?

Comment: I mean the restore option

Answer (score 0):

You cannot undo an instance termination or restore it without a snapshot.  I suggest you enable termination protection on your EC2 instances to protect against accidental termination:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingDisableAPITermination

Comment: The instance was not terminated. It is up and running

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to roll back my instance to a restore default option by changing the root EBS Volume.

Steps to change root EBS volume.

1.stop the instance

2.Create a new EBS volume

3.Detach the existing root EBS Volume

4.Attach the new EBS volume with the device name "/dev/xvda"

5.start the instance"\

Comment: By doing the above method, the instance is getting stopped automatically. "STRANGE"